# Push images/videos to real iOS device

Tags: ios, appium

I was automating one test case where I need to push some images and videos to iOS device. Similar to "adb push" on android. Is there any command line option available to do this. On iOS simulator , I think adding files to "media" folder is enough. Any idea how to achieve this for real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way to do command-line device access is with libimobiledevice: http://www.libimobiledevice.org

In your case, I think you want its patched version of iFuse to mount the app's sandbox into your filesystem.

These are the best docs I could find:

http://cgit.sukimashita.com/ifuse.git/tree/README

Comment: Thanks @Lou Franco. I found libimobiledevice for Mac, But could not see ifuse in tools. Any idea where I can get libimobiledevice compiled for MAC?

Comment: Is ifuse part of libimobiledevice or it's separate library?

Comment: Thanks got it. I saw your comment late.

Comment: Hey @Lou Franco : I could use iFuse from OS X now. Thanks :)